# What are the arguments for and against deprecating transaction priority?

Tags: protocol, transaction-fees, bitcoin-core-development, coin-age-priority

[A recent pull request](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/7022) moves ahead to deprecate the concept of transaction priority by changing the block priority space to zero. This has enraged some users who believe that deprecating transaction priority means that it will no longer be possible to create zero fee transactions.

So what are the arguments for and against deprecating transaction priority?

Comment: Good question, just doesn't have an objective, correct answer. Probably more suitable for reddit.

Comment: Epic comment by confused enraged user jyap808 after having been explained that the issue is not the cause of his problem: "Thanks, I'll stop reading Reddit."

Comment: @JimmySong edited question to make it objective

Answer (score 3):

Since transaction priority has never really been a consensus based "protocol", it was never really that valuable to have it in the core code. Miners can and DO change the priority how they see fit. I see it as less code to maintain in the end and since Bitcoin is meant to be a free market network, the fees paid will prevail